# Struggling in a very basic algebra expression regarding Order of Operation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I had tried expanding along the square for each 2-Ω term but answer came different. And then I tried the latter variation and it worked, turns out I have tried the same sum before:

$(2-Ω)(2-Ω)(2-Ω^2)(2-Ω^2) =(2-Ω)^2(2-Ω^2)^2$ = Gives wrong answer because I expanded first then multiplied the whole mess together :(

$((2-Ω)(2-Ω^2))^2$ = Gives the right answer

I want to know which rule for Order of operations that I don't remember. I tried googling but couldn't make up the question properly so came here so that someone can understand what am I missing.
Thanks

Comment: What's the question?  I don't see what order of operations has to do with this.  The product $A\times A\times B\times B=A^2\times B^2$.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question, the first approach should be correct. The second seems nonsensical.

Comment: EDIT: 2nd expression is WHOLE squared. apologies.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Yes, you can write $A^2\times B^2$ as $(A\times B)^2$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It would help people see where the problem lies if you show a few more intermediate steps, including what the wrong answer was. At the moment all we can say is that the two methods are both correct, and should in principle lead to the same answer.

Comment: These two expressions are equal: $(2-\Omega)^2(2-\Omega^2)^2 = ((2-\Omega)(2-\Omega^2))^2$.

Comment: In the first method, I expanded the squares and multiplied everything thereafter. As algebraic skills are weak, maybe that's why I may have incorrectly performed a step or two during the multiplication simplification process. On the other hand, the second method worked well because kept carrying the whole square until it was just a simple arithmetic expression and then performed the whole sqaure and got the answer.

Comment: But thanks for helping me figure out that both work

Comment: @MohitM Yes, any way of multiplying them works. This is because in multiplication, the order doesn't matter. So $(A A) (BB) = A((AB)B) = (AB)(AB) = \text{etc.}$. So if you get two different results, it means you did something wrong in the calculation. \begin{align*} \\ \end{align*}This is not because "order of operations". This is because what is called the "Commutative Property of Multiplication".